# Bootstrap 4 tabs break in AngularJS

Tags: angularjs, angular-ui-bootstrap, bootstrap-4, angular1.6

I found when using bootstrap tab with pills, the:

```
<a class="nav-link" id="tabItem" data-toggle="pill" href="#tabItem"> example </a>
```

breaks the angular application causing it to navigate back to the page loading the first tab and selecting the first default pill.

I tried adding:

```
_target="self"
```

...adding this fixes navigation only for the first four clicks, and then it breaks again. When I inspect the page I see that the 'active' class never gets cleared with this is set.

I also tried adding:

```
"dependencies": {
     "angular1-ui-bootstrap4": "2.4.22"
 }
```

via npm, but the amount of work needed to create a layout and modify some of the pre-designed behavior wasn't worth my time.

It was a long path to find a minimal-code, tight solution, but I am posting this question to help others.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I fixed this behavior by adding a custom directive in angular that removes the old active class and shows the tab clicked on:

```
//
// when bootstrap adds the # to pills it ruins everything!!
// fix that with this:
//
app.directive('tabFix', function () {
    return function (scope, element, attrs) {
        $(element).click(function (event) {
        $(this).siblings("a").removeClass('active');           
        event.preventDefault();
        $(this).tab('show');         
        });        
    }
});
```

then to call the directive, add tab-fix onto the anchor element:

```
<a class="nav-link" id="tabItem" data-toggle="pill" href="#tabItem" tab-fix> example </a>
```

It fixes everything!